# Conditionally Highlight Differences in Two Ranges of the Same Size

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Can't quite figure this one out.  I have two identically-sized ranges.  I need to highlight the differences on the two sheets.  I would like to do this with a formula.

Here is an example of what I would like to happen.  The first sheet is named Former_Qualifications and looks something like this:

[image]

I would like the second sheet named Current_Qualifications to highlight to show the changes in an employee's qualifications.

[image]

All of the formulas I have used compare a cell to the whole range on the other sheet, not one cell to the same cell on the other sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `custom formula` in your `Current_Qualifications` tab:

```
=B2<>indirect("Former_Qualifications!"&address(row(),column()))
```

***Apply to range:*** `B2:D`

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Works exactly as requested.  I appreciate your fast, accurate response.